Does lack of mental activities reduce "function" of human brain?
On internet there is lots of text how the brain "reduces its function" if you dont  use it.
Quote from link:
"In order to build connections between brain cells, and increase the connections between existing brain cells, you need to use the cells to establish the connection, and then keep using the cells, to maintain that connection."
Is this just speculations or it has been scientifically proven?
If this is true how this mechanism works?

Colloquially this is called "forgetting". Yes, forgetting is proven to exist. Everyone has experienced it personally.

Your link is to a very good article; if you look at the end, you'll see supporting literature (i.e. it's not speculation.) You can learn about how this came to be known by reading the supporting literature, or by reading this Wikipedia entry.
